# Percona 5.7 restarting and drop my connection

Tags: mysql, percona

i have fight with this bug a long time now, when i run scripts to MySQL (Percona) i disconnect me, and when i try to import a mysql dump from a live server its here disconnect me to.

So what i'm fight with its why i got connection refuesed every time i try to running my scripts out or trying to import somthing with my GUI client.

have eny how get this messegt to before and know somebody whats happen here? its a local database on our developer server so its not so crical right now.

> 06:23:02 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ; This could be because you hit a
>   bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the libraries it
>   was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured.
>   This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware. Attempting
>   to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem. As
>   this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
>   collection process might fail. Please help us make Percona Server
>   better by reporting any bugs at http://bugs.percona.com/
>
> key_buffer_size=8388608 read_buffer_size=131072
>   max_used_connections=19 max_threads=152 thread_count=16
>   connection_count=16 It is possible that mysqld could use up to
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
>   68309 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some
>   variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x7f8c80000ae0 Attempting backtrace. You can use the
>   following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no
>   messages after this, something went terribly wrong... stack_bottom =
>   7f8cd0cd0e80 thread_stack 0x30000
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0xe8197c]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x479)[0x797f89]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf8d0)[0x7f8d06efc8d0]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f8d04e82067]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f8d04e83448]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x76c931]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x15d)[0x10cd45d]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20buf_page_io_completeP10buf_page_tb+0x9c0)[0x110eff0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x113c424]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tP5trx_t+0x38)[0x113cc68]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x4a6)[0x110c096]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z27btr_cur_search_to_nth_levelP12dict_index_tmPK8dtuple_t15page_cur_mode_tmP9btr_cur_tmPKcmP5mtr_t+0x5db)[0x10ecdcb]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x103f8a8]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15row_search_mvccPh15page_cur_mode_tP14row_prebuilt_tmm+0x111b)[0x104266b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11ha_innobase13general_fetchEPhjj+0x1bb)[0xf317cb]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler18ha_index_next_sameEPhPKhj+0x141)[0x7fa561]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xc2b8fa]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP7QEP_TABb+0x147)[0xc326d7]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x3b8)[0xc2b198]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12handle_queryP3THDP3LEXP12Query_resultyy+0x238)[0xc9d7a8]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x75f30d]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x342c)[0xc5db8c]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x625)[0xc60d25]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0x877)[0xc61617]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x1b7)[0xc62c27]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x2a0)[0xd257e0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x1b4)[0xe9e804]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x80a4)[0x7f8d06ef50a4]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f8d04f3562d]

The script error from PHP is, and its kind of random what the error is.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Comment: You needed to go further back in the error log.  This message is the *last* one logged.  Details of the fault are prior to this, and "Signal 6" (`SIGABRT`) is thrown by InnoDB when it encounters a condition that is so illogical that continuing cannot possibly be attempted safely. It can be a bug, but it's usually corrupt data caused by faulty hardware (memory or disk). The server deliberately crashes itself when this happens, to protect your data from further corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several reasons for this error. Often this is caused by a corrupt database. Check if this is the case via:

```
mysqlcheck --check --all-databases
```

The PHP exceptions you mentioned aren't important; they are caused by the database crashing, and are an effect rather than a cause.

Comment: i will try to push the command, what i have done for now its remove it and reinstall mysql agin, and its look like its fixed my issue, after i have running a little more testing i will use your command, and thanks for now i will hold you updated.